# Real time JavaScript to razor pages in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Imagine some javascript codes will be add razor pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#photogallery a.lightbox').lightBox();
        $('#photogallery').infiniteCarousel({ imagePath: '/Content/Images/Components/InfiniteCarousel/', autoStart: false });
        $(".flows").collapsiblePanel();
        $(".tab@Model.id").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

This code need some html element defined css class by  .tab and .flows.
There is no sense for flows but .tab@model.id build in run time -because it need model-.

I would like define an attribute for controller method and I would like to add automaticaly with code.

How

```
[JavaScript("menu.js")]
public ActionResult Menu(object param)
{
 return PartialView(this.categoryService.GetAllCategories()[0]);
}
```

and razor view will have automaticaly produced code with

```
...
$(".tab@Model.id").tabs(); 
...
```

Is it phantasy or could be implemented in real life.

Thanks

Comment: note that `tab@Model.id` must be `tab@(Model.id)` due to the fact it looks like an email address.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript block will work fine as-is.
Just put it in the view.

Comment: I am really wondering can I build javascript independed views. Because javascripts can be change by some reason (forexample, today we use one 3th party specific Jquery library, tomorrow I will replace it by another one.) I could have strong attributes (C# attributes) implementation to manage javascript which are have related by model.

Comment: @Nuri: You can put the Javascript in a partial view, then include it in the main view.

Comment: yes, we are using with partial views with @section, but it is not file (as menu.js, collasable.cs) because it has been created in runtime by some jquery selectors reasons. and all request has many times produce javascript and page size always filled by js codes. If I can add to head as *.js's it will cost less than builded js. Am I walking wrong way?

Comment: @Nuri: External scrips are served by separate HTTP requests.  Your model won't exist anymore.

Comment: @SLaks; Now it is clear question, If I have some script tag on view it will get by same reuqest with page. I would like to seperate javascript files from view. When view need any script file i will add this files to head and it will cached by browser and and never requested (while version has same).

Comment: @Nuri: You can't do that, because your model won't exist in the request for the separate script file.  Instead, you can pass any parameters to the script in the querystring, or as variables set in a (small) inline script.